# What's the way to stream teacher's desktop on students' desktop in Windows?

Tags: remote-desktop, shared-access

How do you stream media and text to multiple screens simultaneously with Windows on a private network?

This is our situation: We don't have any projector in our classroom. It's needed to give read-only access to students to see teacher's desktop instantly to be able to know what (s)he's doing. Computer's are connected via a local network.

Comment: There are literally dozens of services that will broadcast your desktop to a session.  Look for group collaboration services.

Comment: There is also software that does that (to be installed on all computers). Asking for that should be done on [SoftwareRecs.SE] (but it needs a [better question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) there).

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_sharing) should get you started.

Comment: There are specialized solutions for this, which work both ways: The teacher can look at pupils’ screens and can also broadcast his own screen. I’ll ask an acquaintance later.

Answer (score 1):

After asking the acquaintance (a teacher), I finally got the name of the software: Master Eye. Unfortunately, it seems to have been discontinued. The successor could be [this program, Mastersolution Suite](http://www.mastersolution.de/klassenraum-management.html). It’s probably available only in German.

I also found this program: [NETOP Vision](http://www.netop.com/classroom-management-software/products/netop-vision.htm).

Both software suites provide a multitude of management functions: Check what each workstation is showing (whether they’re doing the tasks assigned or just browsing the web), blanking the screen so as not to avert attention, as well as showcasing any of the participating workstations to others.

There are probably other programs like those two. Be warned though: school software is a rather peculiar market.

---

I am affiliated with neither of the two companies.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest free way of doing this is VNC.

Install a VNC server on your PC. Then make all your students use a VNC viewer, and tell them to type in your machines IP address. This works very similar to remote desktop if you're familiar with that.

Then you have to uncheck the following boxes in the settings (This is for RealVNC, I'm sure it's similar on others too):

- Accept pointer events from clients
- Accept keyboard events from clients
- Accepts clipboard updates from clients

This way you'll basically be giving them Read-only access!
Happy days!